# How to speed up the query?

Tags: sql-server

Here's my query (it's a part of stored procedure):

```
declare @sql varchar(4000)
declare @tab1 table (ActionID int, ActionDate datetime, [Group] varchar(10), GroupUnicode int, GroupList varchar(100), Artist varchar(250), PlaceName varchar(250),
    ActionType varchar(25), ActionTypeID smallint, ActionPlaceID int, Picture varchar(512), SearchWords varchar(250), ActionEndDate datetime, StrEndDate varchar(250),
    NameForH1 nvarchar(1000), DatesAsPeriod tinyint, DateList varchar(4000))

set @Date2 = DATEADD(day, 1, @Date2)
    insert into @tab1(ActionID, ActionDate, Artist, PlaceName, ActionTypeID, ActionPlaceID, SearchWords, ActionEndDate, StrEndDate, NameForH1, DatesAsPeriod, DateList)
    select X.ID, convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(X.DateList, 1, 19), 120), X.Artist, PlaceName, X.ActionTypeID, X.ActionPlaceID, X.SearchWords, ActionEndDate,
        case when ActionEndDate IS NOT NULL AND convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(X.DateList, 1, 19), 120) < ActionEndDate 
        then ' - ' + convert(varchar, ActionEndDate, 104) + ' ' + convert(varchar(5), ActionEndDate, 108)
        else '' end as StrEndDate, X.NameFOrH1, X.DatesAsPeriod, X.DateList
    from (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
         TOP (100) PERCENT a.ID, a.Artist, a.DateBeg, a.DateEnd, ap.PlaceName, a.ProviderID, a.SubSiteID, a.ActionPlaceID,
         a.CounterAgentID, a.ActionTypeID, a.GenreTypeID, a.ShowTypeID AS ActionShowTypeID, ad.ShowTypeID, ap.CityID, a.ActionPlaceGroupID, 
         a.ActionTopTypeID, a.Canceled, a.ETicketEnabled, st.ShowOnMainPage AS ActionShowOnMainPage, st.ShowInActionList AS ActionShowInActionList, 
         st.ShowInCashdesk AS ActionShowInCashdesk, st1.ShowOnMainPage, st1.ShowInActionList, st1.ShowInCashdesk, a.SearchWords, a.AutoGenerate, 
         ad.ActionEndDate, a.NameForH1, a.CommonActionId, tca.Name AS CommonActionName, a.AgeRestrictionsId, a.DatesAsPeriod,
         dbo.fn_ConvertActionDatesToDateList(a.ID) AS DateList
        FROM dbo.T_Action AS a INNER JOIN
         dbo.T_ActionDates AS ad ON a.ID = ad.ActionID INNER JOIN
         dbo.T_ActionPlace AS ap ON a.ActionPlaceID = ap.ID INNER JOIN
         dbo.T_ShowType AS st ON a.ShowTypeID = st.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.T_ShowType AS st1 ON ad.ShowTypeID = st1.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN                                        
         dbo.T_CommonAction AS tca ON tca.ID = a.CommonActionId
        WHERE (a.Visible = 1)) AS X INNER JOIN dbo.T_Action AS a ON X.ID = a.ID    
where (ActionShowInActionList = 1) and (ShowInActionList = 1)
    and ((X.Artist like '%' + @Artist + '%') or (X.SearchWords like '%' + @Artist + '%'))
    and X.ActionTypeID = case when @ActionTypeID > 0 then @ActionTypeID else X.ActionTypeID end 
    and X.ActionTopTypeID = case when @ActionTopTypeID > 0 then @ActionTopTypeID else X.ActionTopTypeID end 
    and X.GenreTypeID = case when @GenreTypeID > 0 then @GenreTypeID else X.GenreTypeID end 
    and X.ActionPlaceID = case when @ActionPlaceID > 0 then @ActionPlaceID else X.ActionPlaceID end
    and CityID = case when @CityID > 0 then @CityID else CityID end
    and X.ActionPlaceGroupID = case when @GroupPlaceID > 0 then @GroupPlaceID else X.ActionPlaceGroupID end
    and ((convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(X.DateList, 1, 19), 120) = '1980-01-01') 
    or   ((convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(X.DateList, 1, 19), 120) >= @Date1 OR ActionEndDate >= @Date1) AND convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(X.DateList, 1, 19), 120) < @Date2))
order by
    case when @SortBy = 'byPlace' then PlaceName end,
    case when @SortBy = 'byDate' or @SortBy = 'byPlace' then case when convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(X.DateList, 1, 19), 120) = '1980-01-01 00:00' then DATEADD(YY, 1000, convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(X.DateList, 1, 19), 120)) else convert(datetime,            SUBSTRING(X.DateList, 1, 19), 120) end end, Artist, 
    case when @SortBy = 'byAlphabet' then convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(X.DateList, 1, 19), 120) end
```

As you can see, there is nested query and there is the following construction:

```
convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(X.DateList, 1, 19), 120)
```

that repeats several times.

Also, there is the function dbo.fn_ConvertActionDatesToDateList(a.ID):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [fn_ConvertActionDatesToDateList]
(
   @actionId     int
)
RETURNS varchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
   declare @dateList varchar(4000)

   select distinct @dateList = STUFF(CAST((
      SELECT [text()] = ', ' + convert(varchar, ActionDate, 120)
      FROM T_ActionDates where ActionID = a.ID and (ActionDate = '1980-01-01' or ActionDate > GETDATE())
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS VARCHAR(8000)), 1, 2, '') from T_Action as a join T_ActionDates as ad on a.ID = ad.ActionID
      where (ad.ActionDate = '1980-01-01' or ad.ActionDate > GETDATE()) and Visible = 1 and CloseForCorrect = 0 and a.ID = @actionId

   return @dateList
END
```

How can I speed it up?

Comment: You proabably better off speaking with your DBA. They're going to know the table structures (rather than us parsing through them) with their applicable indexes, and optimization procedures relative to your system.

Comment: Why do you think of optimizing this query? Did you tried checking the execution plan? What did it reveal?

Comment: I know it's hard to say something without knowing details, but maybe some kind of general recommendations can take place.

Comment: Right click the screen, choose include execution plan, run the query, look for suggested missing indexes. I see all kinds of things I don't care for in the SQL, but it seems like they are structural design problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really can't tell you exactly  what to do to fix the issue, but I can point out the spots that are almost certainly causing slow down.

1. Ensure your columns in all the joins and WHERE clauses are indexed. There is no way for anyone here to know what is and is not indexed unless you tell us.
2. The sub-select has `TOP (100) PERCENT`. You should not need this.
3. You are generating a likely large sub-set of data by having the sub-select without the improving the WHERE clause in the sub-select. It looks like the WHERE in the main select should be moved into the subselect.
4. Get rid of the sub-select.

With those things said, try this:

```
declare @sql varchar(4000)
declare @tab1 table (ActionID int, ActionDate datetime, [Group] varchar(10), GroupUnicode int, GroupList varchar(100), Artist varchar(250), PlaceName varchar(250),
ActionType varchar(25), ActionTypeID smallint, ActionPlaceID int, Picture varchar(512), SearchWords varchar(250), ActionEndDate datetime, StrEndDate varchar(250),
NameForH1 nvarchar(1000), DatesAsPeriod tinyint, DateList varchar(4000))

set @Date2 = DATEADD(day, 1, @Date2)

insert into @tab1(ActionID, ActionDate, Artist, PlaceName, ActionTypeID, ActionPlaceID, SearchWords, ActionEndDate, StrEndDate, NameForH1, DatesAsPeriod, DateList)
    select
        X.ID, convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(X.DateList, 1, 19), 120), X.Artist, PlaceName, X.ActionTypeID, X.ActionPlaceID, X.SearchWords, ActionEndDate,
        case
            when ActionEndDate IS NOT NULL AND convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(X.DateList, 1, 19), 120) < ActionEndDate 
                then ' - ' + convert(varchar, ActionEndDate, 104) + ' ' + convert(varchar(5), ActionEndDate, 108)
            else ''
        end as StrEndDate
        , X.NameFOrH1, X.DatesAsPeriod, X.DateList
    from (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            a.ID, a.Artist, a.DateBeg, a.DateEnd, ap.PlaceName, a.ProviderID, a.SubSiteID, a.ActionPlaceID,
            a.CounterAgentID, a.ActionTypeID, a.GenreTypeID, a.ShowTypeID AS ActionShowTypeID, ad.ShowTypeID, ap.CityID, a.ActionPlaceGroupID, 
            a.ActionTopTypeID, a.Canceled, a.ETicketEnabled, st.ShowOnMainPage AS ActionShowOnMainPage, st.ShowInActionList AS ActionShowInActionList, 
            st.ShowInCashdesk AS ActionShowInCashdesk, st1.ShowOnMainPage, st1.ShowInActionList, st1.ShowInCashdesk, a.SearchWords, a.AutoGenerate, 
            ad.ActionEndDate, a.NameForH1, a.CommonActionId, tca.Name AS CommonActionName, a.AgeRestrictionsId, a.DatesAsPeriod,
            dbo.fn_ConvertActionDatesToDateList(a.ID) AS DateList
        FROM dbo.T_Action AS a
        INNER JOIN dbo.T_ActionDates AS ad ON a.ID = ad.ActionID
        INNER JOIN dbo.T_ActionPlace AS ap ON a.ActionPlaceID = ap.ID
        INNER JOIN dbo.T_ShowType AS st ON a.ShowTypeID = st.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_ShowType AS st1 ON ad.ShowTypeID = st1.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_CommonAction AS tca ON tca.ID = a.CommonActionId
        WHERE a.Visible = 1
        AND ActionShowInActionList = 1
        and (ShowInActionList = 1)
        and (
                (Artist like '%' + @Artist + '%')
            or  (SearchWords like '%' + @Artist + '%')
        )
        and ActionTypeID = case when @ActionTypeID > 0 then @ActionTypeID else ActionTypeID end 
        and ActionTopTypeID = case when @ActionTopTypeID > 0 then @ActionTopTypeID else ActionTopTypeID end 
        and GenreTypeID = case when @GenreTypeID > 0 then @GenreTypeID else GenreTypeID end 
        and ActionPlaceID = case when @ActionPlaceID > 0 then @ActionPlaceID else ActionPlaceID end
        and CityID = case when @CityID > 0 then @CityID else CityID end
        and ActionPlaceGroupID = case when @GroupPlaceID > 0 then @GroupPlaceID else ActionPlaceGroupID end
        and (
            convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(DateList, 1, 19), 120) = '1980-01-01'
            or  (
                    (
                            convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(DateList, 1, 19), 120) >= @Date1
                        OR  ActionEndDate >= @Date1
                    )
                    AND convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(DateList, 1, 19), 120) < @Date2
                )
        )
    ) AS X
    order by
    case when @SortBy = 'byPlace' then PlaceName end,
    case when @SortBy = 'byDate' or @SortBy = 'byPlace' then case when convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(X.DateList, 1, 19), 120) = '1980-01-01 00:00' then DATEADD(YY, 1000, convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(X.DateList, 1, 19), 120)) else convert(datetime,            SUBSTRING(X.DateList, 1, 19), 120) end end, Artist, 
    case when @SortBy = 'byAlphabet' then convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(X.DateList, 1, 19), 120) end
```

Comment: It seems that calling this function: fn_ConvertActionDatesToDateList is expensive.

Comment: @tesicg Create another question for the Function along with a SQL Fiddle and let's see if we can help :)